# Dynamically escape % sign and brackets { } in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm working on a web application.

I need to escape `%` and `{ }`, if any exists, for further string replacement using either `.format()` or `%s`

I tried `urllib quote_plus`, `re.escape()` but none works.

The string I need to escape is not static.

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For usage with `%`:

```
s = s.replace('%', '%%')
```

For usage with `format`:

```
s = s.replace('{', '{{').replace('}', '}}')
```

Answer (score 0):

To escape `%`, `{` and `}`. You can do this with the `re.sub` method. To escape for  `string.format`:

```
re.sub(r'({|})', '\g<1>\g<1>', original)
```

To escape for `string % args`:

```
re.sub(r'(%)', '\g<1>\g<1>', original)
```

Comment: Or use the string replace method, see eumiro's answer.